# Dropdown Menu submit button

Tags: jquery, button, drop-down-menu

I currently have a drop down menu where I can select a town and it will display records linked to the town when I select it. I was wondering how I could add a button to this so when I select a town, it highlights it and then allows me to click a "submit" button instead of me just selecting the town and automatically showing the data. Here is my current code.

```
$("#myTown option").click(getTown);

function getTown(){
    var town=$(this).val();
    window.location='searchresults.php?querystring='+town+'&querydesc=Town= &querytype=4';
}
```

The button I have beside the drop down menu id is "Search".

Any ideas on the approach I should take is much appreciated.

Comment: can you show your html you need to fire on change event the value in your dropdown changes

Comment: I can't edit the HTML, has to be done through Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of moving the event to the button instead, and then reading the value of the select box:

```
<select id="myTown"></select>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script>
$("#submit").click(getTown);

function getTown(){
 var town=$("#myTown").val();
 window.location='searchresults.php?querystring='+town+'&querydesc=Town= &querytype=4';
}
</script>
```